# rightBarButtonItem not changing color when its disabled in iOS8

Tags: ios8, rightbarbuttonitem

disabling the rightBarButtonItem in iOS8 is not changing its color to grey like in iOS7.Do I have to do anything more to change its color when disabled, other than changing text color color manually.

Comment: I'm seeing this in iOS 7 already. Seems to be an iOS bug.

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative myself. This can be done as follows:

```
[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIColor grayColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```